# Register Knockout.js component viewmodel from module in typescript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, viewmodel, custom-component

My viewmodel module has several classes, so I want to register a spesific class as component's viewmodel.

And it says: **Component 'filter-table': Unknown viewModel value: [object Object]**

This is what I have in my viewmodel module

```
module FilterVM {

export class FilterViewModel {
  //some code
}

class FilterTableViewModel {
} 

class AttributeTableViewModel {
}

class LayerAttributeViewModel {
}

}
export = FilterVM;
```

And this where I am trying to register

```
import FilterVM = require('Scripts/App/Components/AttributeTable/ViewModels/FilterViewModel');


ko.components.register('filter-table', {
        viewModel: { require: FilterVM.FilterViewModel },
        template: { require: 'text!Scripts/App/Components/AttributeTable/Views/FilterTableView.html' }
    });
```

**What is wrong with that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was here  `viewModel: { require: FilterVM.FilterViewModel }`

Should be   `viewModel: FilterVM.FilterViewModel`

Answer (score 0):

> `require('Scripts/App/Components/AttributeTable/ViewModels/FilterViewModel');`

You probably need to change this into a *relative* path. Even though TypeScript finds it at compile time ... the runtime library may not. Use something like `require('../AttributeTable/ViewModels/FilterViewModel');` etc.

Comment: that does not work for me.

If I put 
viewModel: { require: 'Scripts/App/Components/AttributeTable/ViewModels/FilterViewModel' } works if the file has only one class, I want to choose a spesific class from many